# Is wordpress 3.3.1 compatible with PHP Version 5.2.17?

Tags: compatibility

Exactly what it says on the tin, I am having a few problems with my site after a server upgrade and some of it has started to trip out.

A lot of my code has also stopped working, despite it doing nothing fancy, mostly just loops and ifs just wondering if because a lot of it is dependant on WP functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. From the [requirements page](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/):

> - PHP version 5.2.4 or greater
> - MySQL version 5.0 or greater

You don't need an update, try the various [debug tools](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see what goes wrong.

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 > 5.2.4 ...

Comment: Oh dammit, have to sleep again. :D